# PCEP-SR draft version 6, SR Explicit Route Object/Record Route Object subobjects

Tags: opendaylight

I am setting up Segment routing via Pathman-SR with ODL Nitrogen Controller and vMX Juniper routers. To allow this, I have to change IANA subojbects code points, but I am unable to do it...

Followed this documenntations, but still no result:
https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-carbon/user-guide/pcep-user-guide.html#segment-routing
https://test-odl-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/pcep-user-guide.html

I tried to update configuration via REST API, but when I send PUT request:
/restconf/config/pcep-segment-routing-app-config:pcep-segment-routing-app-config

with the body:

```
<pcep-segment-routing-config xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:pcep:segment-routing-app-config">
   <iana-sr-subobjects-type>true</iana-sr-subobjects-type>
</pcep-segment-routing-config>
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "error": [
            {
                "error-type": "protocol",
                "error-tag": "invalid-value",
                "error-message": "URI has bad format. Possible reasons:\n 1. \"pcep-segment-routing-app-config:pcep-segment-routing-app-config\" was not found in parent data node.\n 2. \"pcep-segment-routing-app-config:pcep-segment-routing-app-config\" is behind mount point. Then it should be in format \"/yang-ext:mount/pcep-segment-routing-app-config:pcep-segment-routing-app-config\"."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a typo in the URL in the doc, you have to use /restconf/config/pcep-segment-routing-app-config:pcep-segment-routing-config

You can check this guide for reference:
https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/bgpcep/en/stable-neon/pcep/pcep-user-guide-active-stateful-pce.html#iana-code-points